# SASS: Looping through nested list "…is not a map for `map-get'"

Tags: sass

I try to loop through a map in SASS, but it's not working as expected.

Given the following list:

```
$names: (
  peter: (
    color: #f00,
    height: 20px,
    name: first
  ),
  susan: (
    color: #0f0,
    height: 40px,
    name: second
  )
);
```

I want to loop through it and create a CSS output like this:

```
.first {
  color: #0f0,
  height: 40px,
}

.second {
  color: #0f0,
  height: 40px,
}
```

To do that, I try to create a a mixin that loops through the map and outputs its values to CSS:

```
@mixin classes($map) {
  @each $key in $map {
    .#{map-get(map-get($key, $map), name)} {
      // Rules
    }
  }
}

@include classes($names);
```

Unfortunately the loop does not run, it quits with this error message:

```
$map: ("peter" (color: #f00, height: 20px, name: first)) is not a map for `map-get'
```

What am I doing wrong, is it not possible to nest calls to `map-get`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error should be a dead giveaway as to what is happening.  Sass is interpreting your mapping as a list.  This is happening because you're using the syntax for looping over a list, not a mapping.  If you only pull a single value out of your mapping via `@each`, Sass casts it to a list.

```
@mixin classes($map) {
  @each $key, $val in $map {
    .#{map-get($val, name)} {
      // Rules
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I wasn't aware that this syntax is possible, but of course it makes sense.